# All these Crossy Road questions

Tags: discussion, questions

Ok, I gotta ask.  There've been [more than](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116327/creating-slide-in-text?s=1%7C0.0000) a [few](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/113275/which-font-does-crossy-road-use?s=4%7C0.0000) *Crossy Road* [related](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116496/button-designs-download) questions [recently](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116077/how-to-implement-good-gui-design-in-unity) (with some others I probably can't see because they'd have been deleted).

I happened to notice that that third one (posted a few minutes prior to this meta question) was posted by a [user](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/78993/mendls) who has no other posts anywhere, yet has already been temp-banned for rules violations.  So I looked at the three other Crossy Road questions I could find, which were *also* posted by 1-rep [users](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/78857/victor) ([two of which](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/69956/the-game-changer) are *also* [temp-banned](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/78635/hector)).

Is this actually one (really persistent) person?

Comment: It's a future millionaire, creating a backstory about how he had to overcome numerous challenges in creating his perfect flappy bird clone that made him rich. Or it's a person creating multiple accounts to avoid their initial suspension from asking off-topic questions. Our site is just that good, that people would rather go through all the work of creating multiple accounts, rather than ask somewhere else.

Comment: @Byte56 I like the future millionaire idea. ;D

Comment: Josh has most of the actual details, I've been mostly out of the loop on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accounts in question are all suspended for serious breaches of terms of service that aren't *directly* related to the public content they have individually posted.

Comment: I figured as much, I was curious if they were controlled by the same human being. Just sheer curiosity due to the prevalence of questions regarding the same publish game title.  e.g. I know that getting around a ban is itself a bannable offense, but it requires knowing that the user accounts are related.  Should I flag future questions for this reason?

Comment: If you have reason to suspect a user's up to no good, whether related to this scenario or others, then yes, you can flag posts for moderator attention, it will certainly help.